# Flutter: Make Buttons stretch

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I having an issue with a Flutter Widget tree I am building:

[image]

I Want the Buttons on the Bottom to be bigger and fill all the available space from the text above to the bottom of the screen.

Here my current Code:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          UpperDetailsContainer(),
          TitleAndPrice(),
          //The Row below contains the Two Buttons
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: size.width / 2,
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Text("Buy Now"),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(50)
                        )
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: size.width / 2,
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Text("Description"),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(50)
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have already tried:

- Making the upper widgets smaller
- Adding Mainaxisaligment.spacebetween to the surrounding column
- Adding Crossaxisaligment.stretch to the Row that contains the buttons
- Removing SafeArea bottom / SafeArea as a whole
- Setting the height for the buttons manually as an absolute value, but I don't really wanna do this for obvious reasons

What else can i do? And where does that grey bottom Stripe come from?

Comment: Did you try to wrap them in `Expanded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to the row, so that it fills all available vertical space

note: you need the `Expanded` widget so that the constraint your row gets, isn't infinite

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: size.height * 0.7,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _buildBuyNowButton(size),
              _buildDescriptionButton(size),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Runnable example: https://www.dartpad.dev/4f568d8e0a334d23e7211207081356b4?null_safety=true

Comment: `Adding Crossaxisaligment.stretch to the Row that contains the buttons` - unless the problem is caused by other widgets which code you haven't posted, my answer should work. If that's not the case, please update the answer with additional code, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the effort with the dartpad. The problem was indeed that i actually hadn't  tried to put the CrossAxisAlignment.stretch onto the Row() which contained the two button (- containers), I just thought I did (or maybe the emulator didn't reload properly) .